# test method code coverage

Tags: class, unit-test

this class and I need to turn up the code coverage of 78 to 100

The class

```
public class AlsurOrderAssignment {

    public CPA_Order_Allocation__c allocation { get; set; }
    public List<CPA_Order_Allocation__c> currentAllocations { get; set; }
    public String association { get; set; }
    public String order {get; set;}
    public CPA_Order__c orderObject { get; set; }
    public Map<Id, CPA_Order__c> orderObjects { get; set; }

    public AlsurOrderAssignment() {
        allocation = new CPA_Order_Allocation__c(Number_of_Units_of_Presentation__c=0.00);
        orderObjects = new Map<Id, CPA_Order__c>();
    }
    public void findOrder() {
        System.debug(orderObjects.size());
        orderObject = orderObjects.get(order);System.debug('we got here');
        currentAllocations = [Select Id,
                                    Association__c,
                                    Association__r.Name,
                                    Number_of_Units_of_Presentation__c,
                                    Number_of_Kilos__c,
                                    Number_of_Baskets__c
                                From
                                    CPA_Order_Allocation__c
                                where
                                    CPA_Order__c=:order];
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getOrderItems() {

        List<CPA_Order__c> orders = [Select Id,
                                            Client__c,
                                            Product_Name__c,
                                            Unallocated_Units_of_Presentation__c,
                                            Unallocated_Number_of_Kilos__c,
                                            Unallocated_Number_of_Baskets__c,
                                            Client_Product_Association__c,
                                            Order_Code__c,
                                            Expected_Delivery_Date__c,
                                            Unit_of_Presentation__c,
                                            Presentacion__c
                                        from 
                                            CPA_Order__c
                                        where
                                            Expected_Delivery_Date__c = LAST_N_DAYS:5
                                        and 
                                            Unallocated_Units_of_Presentation__c > 0];

        orderObjects.putAll(orders);
        System.debug(orderObjects.size());
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        for (CPA_Order__c order : orders) {
            options.add(new SelectOption(order.Id, order.Order_Code__c));
        }
        return options;
    }

    public PageReference saveAllocation() {
        allocation.CPA_Order__c = order;
        allocation.Association__c = association;
        insert allocation;
        PageReference currentPage = ApexPages.currentPage();
        currentPage.setRedirect(true);
        return currentPage;
    }
    public List<SelectOption> getAssociationItems() {
        list<Association__c> associations = [Select Id, Name from Association__c];
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        for (Association__c association : associations) {
            options.add(new SelectOption(association.Id, association.Name));
        }
        return options;
    }
}
```

The Test Class

```
@isTest 
private class testAlsurOrderAssignment{
    @isTest
    static void validateAlsurOrderAssignment(){
        // 1. Set things up
        Association__c association = new Association__c();
        association.Name = 'Alsurtest';
        insert association;

        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.FirstName = 'pedrito';
        contact.LastName = 'perez';
        insert contact;

        CPA_Order__c order = new CPA_Order__c();
        order.Number_of_Units_of_Presentation__c = 10;
        order.Contact__c = contact.Id;
        order.Expected_Delivery_Date__c = System.today();
        order.Unit_of_Presentation__c = '5';
        insert order;

        CPA_Order_Allocation__c allocation = new CPA_Order_Allocation__c();
        allocation.CPA_Order__c = order.Id;
        allocation.Association__c = association.Id;
        allocation.Number_of_Units_of_Presentation__c = 5;
        allocation.Number_of_Kilos__c = 5;
        insert allocation;

        CPA_Order_Allocation__c[] allocations = [SELECT Id, CPA_Order__c from CPA_Order_Allocation__c where CPA_Order__c =: order.Id];
        System.assertEquals(allocations.size(), 1);

        // 2. Run the code you want to test
        // Run findOrder() method
        AlsurOrderAssignment assignmentClass = new AlsurOrderAssignment();

        assignmentClass.getOrderItems();
        System.assert(assignmentClass.orderObjects.size() > 0);    

        List<SelectOption> options = assignmentClass.getAssociationItems();
        System.assert(options != null);

        assignmentClass.findOrder();
        System.assert(assignmentClass.orderObjects.size() > 0);
    }
}
```

TKS

Comment: Which lines are you having trouble covering? If you update your question to make that clearer it might be easier to get help.

Comment: Hi the lines i need to cover are

    public PageReference saveAllocation() {
        allocation.CPA_Order__c = order;
        allocation.Association__c = association;
        insert allocation;
        PageReference currentPage = ApexPages.currentPage();
        currentPage.setRedirect(true);
        return currentPage;
    }

Answer (score 3):

To increase your code coverage, find out the lines that are not being covered using the dev console.

Once you have an Idea of the lines not covered, create scenarios in you test methods that will satisfy the criteria of the lines not covered.

You may have to write separate methods to cover these specific scenerios.

In addition, 100% coverage all the time is an unrealistic goal. Properly asserting your business processes and expected results along with any negative test case should routinely yield 90%+ coverage which is more than adequate. It is not about the percentage anyway it is about the amount of the business process and asserting results that you cover that is important.